# bool to break a while loop - return of a function keeps switching back

Tags: python

having trouble getting this function to work:

```
go_on = False
def keep_going():
    further = input("input: ")
    if further == "n":
        go_on = True
    else:
        go_on = False
    return go_on

while go_on == False:
    keep_going()
```

The idea being, that if you put in 'n', the while loop gets interrupted, obviously 
But even if the function returns **True** after the input is 'n', the name `go_on` keeps switching to **False**.

Comment: The function’s return is not being assigned to anything. That aside, this setup has several flaws; suggesting there is a deeper issue here which is not described in the question.

Comment: There are two different `go_on` variables in your code. Assigning to the local variable `go_on` in `keep_going` doesn't change the value of the global variable `go_on`.

Comment: Would https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python answer your question?

Comment: @Brian - I've edited the two different ones for clarification - thought it didn't matter to use the same name, since they are in fact different anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually assign the returned the value of `keep_going` to be used by the loop

```
go_on = False
def keep_going():
    go_on = input("input: ")
    if go_on == "n":
        go_on = True
    else:
        go_on = False
    return go_on

while go_on == False:
    go_on = keep_going()
```

It's also important to understand *why* this is needed. The `go_on` declared on line 1 isn't scoped to any function where as the `go_on` assigned with `input` is locally scoped to the function `keep_going`. It's important to understand that these are two **different** variables. When using `go_on` inside of the function the scope will default to that of the function. This means your assignments and return statement only edit the local variable and not the global like you may expect.

Comment: is is worth explaining why the `go_on` in the method isn't the same `go_on` as at the top of the script? Seems like there's also some variable scope confusion

Comment: @Basic that's a very good point. I edited my comment to add a little extra context.

Comment: a simple `global go_on` inside the function seems to work then

Comment: @gurkenmeister you are correct that a single global `go_on` will work. That being said, if you went that route you should not return anything from `keep_going` or assign the result in your loop.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer identifies why your code isn't working as expected, but it's worth noting you could simplify this entire process down to:

```
while input("input: ") != "n":
    pass
```

Comment: Thx for the info - trying to call the function in another program to end the program loop. Got to check that out, if it's usable instead.

Comment: It sounds like you have an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). It might be worth asking another question with a larger context. It's quit uncommon to call functions in another process. Python multiprocessing supports it, but it's for rather esoteric use-cases and unlikely to be what you actually need.  Do you want 2 processes to exchange data? Or do you want one process to control the flow of another? Or monitor execution and recover? Or ... You get the picture, and they all have their own solutions.

Comment: Just playing around with code, trying to learn something ...